# Custom Collection View cards and spinning wheels

Tags: flutter

I'm considering the feasibility of rewriting [an iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/is/app/nefna/id648680743) in Flutter, as adapting to the ever increasing number of screen sizes in the iOS ecosystem has become tedious.

The app sports a customised UICollectionView, where cards can be scrolled while rotating like playing cards, and there is a spinning wheel for random selection.

What widgets should I start looking into, to recreate this behaviour?  Do you think it's likely that I'd be successful in that recreation with Flutter?

The collection view can contain thousands of entries - could I expect high performance with something analogous in Flutter?

Those app features in action can be seen here: https://photos.app.goo.gl/H3wmrGR6RDaY7YDz5

Comment: I am also looking for the results in the second tab click and swiping cards in semi circle . Did you found any solution?

Comment: Haven't found one yet, but that may be due to the fact that I haven't been actively looking :)

Comment: OK. thanks for the update. I am also working on it . Will post my answer here as its done